# webstart-maven-plugin can not sign jar due to timestamp request rejection

Tags: jar-signing, maven-webstart-plugin

We have a project using [webstart-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/webstart-maven-plugin) to create a Java Webstart JNLP artefact.

But on maven compile I always get

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-6:jnlp-download-servlet
>   (default) on project webstart: Could not sign jar
>   ...\target\jnlp\libs\unprocessed_commons-codec-1.10.jar, use -X to
>   have detail of error

Running with with -X reveals:

> jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.io.IOException: Error generating
>   timestamp: the timestamp request was rejected. Unrecognized or
>   unsupported algorithm identifier.

Due to [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-7102686) I updated my JDK to 1.8 (just for testing purposes, since I currently still need 1.7 for the product):

```
java -version  
java version "1.8.0_172"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime    Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
```

but still I'm getting the error above.

To get the timestamp we are using the URL http://sha1timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha1/timestamp, see maven plugin config below.

My problem is: For my colleages it works, they have same Java version, same maven project setup etc.
Therefore it has to be a problem in my local environment. Any ideas?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jnlp-download-servlet</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputJarVersions>true</outputJarVersions>
        <outputDirectoryName>webstart</outputDirectoryName>
        <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
        <templateDirectory>src/main/resources/jnlp</templateDirectory>
        <libPath>libs</libPath>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <unsignAlreadySignedJars>true</unsignAlreadySignedJars>
        <jnlpFiles>
            <jnlpFile>
                <templateFilename>abc.vm</templateFilename>
                <outputFilename>abc.jnlp</outputFilename>
                <jarResources>
                    ...
                </jarResources>
            </jnlpFile>
        </jnlpFiles>
        <sign>
            <keystore>${pathKeystore}</keystore>
            <storepass>${passstore}</storepass>
            <keypass>${passkey}</keypass>
            <alias>${alias}</alias>
            <tsaLocation>${tsaLocation}</tsaLocation>
            <arguments>
                <argument>-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${project.build.directory}/../myTruststore.jks</argument>
                <argument>-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=myPassword</argument>
                <argument>-J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${project.build.directory}/../myTruststore.jks</argument>
                <argument>-J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=myPassword</argument>
                <argument>-J-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.mycompany.com</argument>
                <argument>-J-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128</argument>
                <argument>-J-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.mycompany.com</argument>
                <argument>-J-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128</argument>
            </arguments>

        </sign>
        <unsign>true</unsign> <!-- unsign already signed packages and sign them with own key -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>

...         
<tsaLocation>http://sha1timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha1/timestamp</tsaLocation>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Build works when I remove

```
<tsaLocation>${tsaLocation}</tsaLocation>
```

from the sign configuration --> no timestamp is fetched from the timestamp server, but the jars are signed.

Comment: This simply means that you are not using any timestamp server, which is not advisable. You will get the following error if you followed the above method: "Warning:
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2022-07-01) or after any future revocation date."